# How to hide and redirect multiple directories in urls starting with same domain using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

url-11:[www.example.com/names/one/tempo.php?color=red&model=small&speed=1](http://www.example.com/directory1/folder1/file1.php)

suppose i want to hide "names" to have the url as

url-12:[www.example.com/one/tempo.php?color=red&model=small&speed=1](http://www.example.com/directory1/folder1/file1.php)

**First the url-11 to be redirected to url-12 on the address bar, then internally url-12 should display the contents of url-11.**
the htaccess goes this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+names/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^names/)^(.*)$ /names/$1 [L,NC]
```

how do i rewrite for the second url-2: [www.example.com/biking/two/bike.php?make=yamaha&gears=5&oil=castrol&page=2](http://www.example.com/directory1/folder1/file1.php)

to have the url-2: [www.example.com/two/bike.php?make=yamaha&gears=5&oil=castrol&page=2](http://www.example.com/directory1/folder1/file1.php)

and the third  url-3: [www.example.com/cars/three/cycle.php?hero=nice](http://www.example.com/directory1/folder1/file1.php)
as url-3: [www.example.com/three/cycle.php?hero=nice](http://www.example.com/directory1/folder1/file1.php)

the above rewrite works for only one directory, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  ^folder(\d+)/file(\d+).php directory$1/folder$2/file$3.php [QSA]
```

Comment: sir, appreciate your answer but i have altered the question with different folders and also added variable parameters

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^names(/one/.*) $1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^biking(/two/.*) $1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^cars(/three/.*) $1 [R=301]
```

Comment: SIR, First the url-11 to be redirected to url-12 on the address bar, then internally url-12 should display the contents of url-11.

Comment: this redirects externally but does not redirect internally gives error